# Implement a reverse function to reverse an integer but the output here is always 0

Tags: c, integer

I do not understand why the return .... does not work. Somehow, Output is always 0. Here the return call to `atoi` always outputs 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>  //INCLUDES
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse (int x); //Func Decls

int
main ()
{
  printf ("%d", reverse (123)); //123=321, -123=-321, 120=21, 0=0
  return 0;
}

int
reverse (int x)
{

  int i, rem = 0;
  char arr[15];

  while (x % 10 != 0)
    {
      rem = x % 10;
      arr[i] = ((char)rem);
      x /= 10;
      i++;
    }

  return atoi(arr); //OUTPUT = 0, does not return actual output
}
```

Comment: The character representation of a digit is not the same as its numerical value.  Typically you can do '`0' + rem` to get the character representation of a digit.

Comment: `char arr[15] = "";` to fill with `0`. Then `while (x) { ... }` and `arr[i] = rem + '0';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you can fix your code a little bit to make it works. Below is my opinion:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //INCLUDES
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse (int x); //Func Decls

int main () {
  printf ("%d", reverse (123)); //123=321, -123=-321, 120=21, 0=0
  return 0;
}

int reverse (int x) {

  int i, rem = 0;
  int arr[15];

  while (x != 0)
    {
      rem = x % 10;
      arr[i] = rem;
      x /= 10;
      i++;
    }
    
  int result = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    result = 10 * result + arr[j];
  }


  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the usage of `atoi()` function. The `atoi()` function basically converts a string with numeric characters codified in ASCII to an integer.
If you look the [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table, the numbers 1, 2 and 3 codify the characters `'^A'`, `'^B'` and `'^C'`, respectively. This means that, after the `while` loop in `reverse()` function, the string passed as argument to `atoi()` is not a numeric string, so zero is returned as an error. Also, the characters `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` are codified as numbers 49, 50 and 51, respectively.

Now, I suggest you to change your entire implementation, because it does not make sense to receive an integer as input to operate with and, during the operation, convert it to string to return an integer again using `atoi()`. So, forget strings, [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), and `atoi()`.
Lets start creating a loop to operate with each digit of the number, using the module operator, as you did.

```
int reverse (int x) {
    int result = 0;
    while ( x != 0 ) {
        result = x%10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then, to insert another digit to the `result`, do the opposite: multiply it by 10.

```
int reverse (int x) {
    int result = 0;
    while ( x != 0 ) {
        result = result*10 + x%10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, cut the target digit out of the `x`, dividing it by ten.

```
int reverse (int x) {
    int result = 0;
    while ( x != 0 ) {
        result = result*10 + x%10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, the entire code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse (int x);

int main () {
    printf ("%d\n", reverse(123));
    printf ("%d\n", reverse(-123));
    printf ("%d\n", reverse(120));
    printf ("%d\n", reverse(0));
    return 0;
}

int reverse (int x) {
    int result = 0;
    while ( x != 0 ) {
        result = result*10 + x%10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the result, as expected:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o program program.c
$ ./program
321
-321
21
0
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array nor `atoi` function for this task, and the logic of `while` loop is not correct. A correct and simple one could be something like that (provided that no integer overflow occurs):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse (int x)
{
    int r = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        r = 10 * r + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return r;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n", reverse(1234));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
int i, rem = 0;
```

and

```
arr[i] = ((char)rem);
```

the local variable `i` in not initialized!.  on my system the result is a seg fault event.